# Footer in listfragment (listview)

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to add a static footer to a list view for android.  I'm using a list fragment, a listview that fills the parent, and loading it from the main activity.  I want to add a footer to the list view so I created a footer xml file but I can't load it from within the list fragment.  It either crashes or nothing happens.

What's the correct code for loading a static footer in a listview inside a listfragment?  Any code snippets I reference don't work when pasting inside listfragment extended class.

I get this error when it's crashing 'viewpager layout params cannot be cast to abslistviewlayoutparams' or something like that, the viewpager is the main parent and each tab is a fragment, one of these fragments is a listview where I'm trying to add a footer to.

```
<!--This is the fragment with the list in it-->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

     <include layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
     <ListView
          android:id="@+id/list"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks.  Below code I just tried, compiles and runs but does nothing. and it's inside the 
onCreateView method and it's a class extending ListFragment.

```
     lview = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);            

     //nothing happens using this    
     lview.addFooterView(
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.standalone_footer, null)
      );

      //crashes with cast exception using this
      lview.addFooterView(
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.standalone_footer, container, false)      
     );

//onCreate method, either crashes or runs but nothing happens when tweaking code
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)        {

     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab1, container, false);

     lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);

     mItems = new ArrayList<ListViewCustom>();

     //add static fixed footer
     lv.addFooterView(
             inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null, false)     //also tried passing lv instead of null 
     );

     //initialize and set the list adapter
     setListAdapter(new ListViewAdapterCustom(getActivity(), mItems));

     return view;
}
```

Stand alone footer xml (TableLayout with xmlns tags aren't showing as code in here...)
     
      android:stretchColumns="*"
      android:background="#000">

```
<TableRow
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal">

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"  
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />                         
</TableRow>

<TableRow
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="center_horizontal">

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  
         android:text="0"  
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
         android:text="0"  
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />

     <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  
         android:text="0"  
         android:layout_span="1" 
         android:layout_weight="1" 
         android:gravity="center" />
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

PS Listfragment and actual list loads and renders fine, everything with that works properly.  I am using a custom adapter too if that matters?

Comment: Add the layouts too please.

Comment: Can you add the entirety of your `onCreateView` method?

Comment: I'll edit the post to include it.  I guess more explanation is that I'm using a swipe view with tabs and each tab is a fragment, one of these tabs is a listfragment that shows a listview and I'm trying to add a footer to the listview.

Answer (score 1):

`view = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);`
I don't understand this part -- your base view is called `view` (as seen when you call `view.findViewById`, but you are also calling your `ListView` to be `view` as well.

Try this within your `onCreateView()` method:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list);
lv.addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.standalone_footer, null));
```

Or try `getListView().addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.standalone_footer, null))`

Comment: view was just in the context of that snippet, I understand the confusing since a parameter being passed into onCreateView is also a view.  So your code just renamed it to lv, it didn't change anything and it still doesn't wok.  In this case it compiles but nothing happens.  What I'm trying to load has a table view and table rows in it for the footer xml if that means anything.

Comment: getListView() will cause null pointer exception, it isn't ready in onCreateView, I have to use the view I am inflating and going to return from that function.